# Where is NLS_CHARACTERSET parameter in Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g?

Tags: oracle

Did logged into Enterprise Manager 11g via browser. There are `NLS_TERRITORY`, `NLS_LANGUAGE` and other `NLS` related params in In `Server->Initialization Parameter->NLS group`. But unable to find `NLS_CHARACTERSET` parameter. Explicit search of the parameters gives

> "No parameters found".

Is "select * from nls_database_parameters" the only way to view its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from @OraNob gave me

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

However this worked for me:

```
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET');
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'
```

Comment: The question was where the setting is in Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g when you open it in a browser.